# Can delegation constructor in C++ be called in the body or just in the initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11

as the title says I am curious if delegation constructor can be called in the body or not.

If you are curious about motivation:
I have some condition and only workaround I found requires having uselss write on dummy member that occupies space.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Delegating {
Delegating (const string& str) {
        cout <<"const string& \n";
}
Delegating(string&& str): dummy_(str.size()>4 ? 0 : (Delegating(str),0))     {
       if (str.size()>4) {
          cout <<"string&& \n";
       }
}
bool dummy_;
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Delegating("abc");
    Delegating("abcde");
    Delegating("abcde");
    Delegating("abcde");
    Delegating("abc");
    cout << "\n--------------------\n";
    Delegating(string("abc"));
    Delegating(string("abcde"));
    Delegating(string("abcde"));
    Delegating(string("abcde"));
    Delegating(string("abcde"));
    Delegating(string("abc"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you want a named constructor.

Comment: Note that here you don't call delegated constructor but create a temporary.

Comment: Your motivation is unclear for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code does not do what you think it does. By adding a verbose destructor :

```
~Delegating() {
    std::cout << "~\n";   
}
```

... the output becomes :

```
const string& 
~
~
string&& 
~
string&& 
~
string&& 
~
const string& 
~
~
--------------------
(and so on)
```

Notice there are seven destructor calls, whereas you only instanciated five objects. That's because in the following line :

```
Delegating(string&& str): dummy_(str.size()>4 ? 0 : (Delegating(str),0)) {
```

... `Delegating(str)` is not a delegated constructor call, but an independent temporary object, which is created and destructed during the initialization of `dummy_`.

The only syntax for delegating constructors is :

```
Foo(/* params */) : Foo(/* other params */), /* members-init */ {}
//      First one ! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... and it is not possible to conditionally delegate. You can resort to a static function that does the check, and returns a suitably-constructed object (a.k.a the "Named Constructor Pattern").

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already pointed out that you if call a constructor from inside a constructor then you are creating a temporary. I would like to point out that your test cases never call the constructor `Delegating (const string& str)` directly. In all those cases, `Delegating(string && str)` is a better fit.

Try the following code that uses named constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Delegating
{
    Delegating()
    {
        cout << "default \n";
    };

    Delegating( const string & str )
    {
        cout << "const string & \n";
    }

    Delegating( const string && str )
    {
        cout << "string && \n";
    }

    static Delegating constr( const string & a_Str )
    {
        cout << a_Str.data() << '\t';
        return Delegating( a_Str );
    }

    static Delegating constr( string && x_Str )
    {
        cout << x_Str.data() << '\t';
        if ( x_Str.size() > 4 )
            return Delegating();
        else
            return Delegating( x_Str );
    }

    ~Delegating()
    {
        cout << "~\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Delegating::constr( "abc" );
        Delegating::constr( "abcde" );
        cout << "\n--------------------\n";
        Delegating::constr( string( "abc" ) );
        Delegating::constr( string( "abcde" ) );
        cout << "\n--------------------\n";
        string d_Named( "abc" );
        Delegating::constr( d_Named );
        d_Named = "abcde";
        Delegating::constr( d_Named );
    }
    return 0;
}
```